# O ícone da notificação modifica com app fechado

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Quando o App esta aberto o ícone aparece normal, agora quando o app não esta aberto aparece apenas um circulo no lugar do ícone. Tenho um sistema em Swing que quando o usuário faz uma certa ação é enviado uma notificação.

**Código que fica no sistema em Swing**

```
    public void enviaNotificacaoDenunciaFcm(String tkn, String corpo) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=chave do fcm");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("to", tkn);

        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("title", "Secretaria do Meio Ambiente");   // Notification title
        info.put("body", corpo); // Notification body
        info.put("color", "blue");

        json.put("notification", info);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(json.toString());
        wr.flush();
        conn.getInputStream();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao enviar notificação!\n" + e, "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        atualizaTabela();
        desabilitaBotoes();
        desabilitaCampos();
        limpaCampos();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao enviar notificação!\n" + e, "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    // return null;
}
```

[image: ao clicar no Salvar é enviada a Notificação]

[image: Notificação com App Aberto]

[image: Notificação com App Fechado]

Comment: não sei o motivo do negativo já que expliquei tudo direitinho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basta colocar o codigo abaixo no AndroidManifest.xml, conforme o:  https://vike.io/pt/408790/

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/blue_dark" />
```